# Unpivot repeating groups of columns into rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with data in this format
[image: Current data]

but I would like it reshaped to look like this

[image: Desired Data]

I've attempted Transposing the data using the code provided at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112210/unpivot-in-google-sheets-multipe-header-columns-and-rows) however the result is not what I want, and I can't seem to get my head around it. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but the need to work with grouped columns is throwing me a little. I'm used to Python Pandas, and my Excel/Sheets skills are severely lacking.

I've provided all spreadsheets and an example of the use of the linked function in [this demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RCuMmwpjswEvXJkRvl6wUBbe_wyDfAbTfx5DRGauBes/edit?usp=sharing).

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I should have clarified. I'm trying to do this specifically in Google Sheets, I've tagged it with Excel in case the process is the same and those with Excel expertise could weigh in.

Comment: Have you considered using Apps Script to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new tab on your sheet called MK.Help.  You will find this formula in cell A2.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(current_data!A3:A&"|"&current_data!B3:B&"|"&current_data!C3:C&"|"&FILTER(current_data!D3:L,REGEXMATCH(current_data!D2:L2,"size"))&"|"&FILTER(current_data!D3:L,REGEXMATCH(current_data!D2:L2,"colour"))&"|"&FILTER(current_data!D3:L,REGEXMATCH(current_data!D2:L2,"quantity"))),"|",0,0),"where Col4<>''"))
```

Caveat:
I should mention that FLATTEN() is an undocumented function that I only recently discovered.  I've believe it is intended to remain "hidden" in the back end of the sheets programming, but if what I did is what you're after, there really isn't a more efficient way to do it.  If you're uncomfortable using an undocumented function, let me know and I can try to build a different kind of work around for you.  I have spoken to an engineer at Google and was told that it wasn't going anywhere, but there are also no plans to make it "public".

Comment: Thanks for this Matt. That's one hell of a formula, but it is more transparent than the script I'm using so I like it. I will have to pick over it to make sure I understand each sfage

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was misusing the script in the linked answer. I didn't have headings. Once I provided headings to group the columns the unpivot script worked perfectly. I'll leave the example sheets for people to view with the answer.

Comment: I can do this with a fairly simple single arrayformula if you're interested?  If your script is good then so be it :) but if you're interested in how to do it with a formula, maybe change the sheet to editable, and I can demo it on a new tab.

Comment: Hi @MattKing. That would be really helpful, and if there is a simpler native solution I'd like to see it. I think I've made the doc editable now. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! is it definitely just 3 "products"? would you like it to plan for indefinite numbers of products?

Comment: 3 was just for the example. It is more an indefinite figure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this query formula:

```
=QUERY({A2:F5;A3:C5,G3:I5;A3:C5,J3:L5},"where Col4<>'' order by Col1")
```

*(no need for a script)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)