# how do you summarize and then traspose the results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

This image shows what i am needing to achieve. I dont know how to do it.
Any help will be welcome.

[image]

Comment: What program? Excel, Google Sheets, or LibreOffice Calc? The approach will be different depending on which one. Look up reverse pivoting.

Comment: Ideally google-sheets. But if there is a solution in the other spreadhseet will also help. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954722/how-do-you-create-a-reverse-pivot-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&"♀"&B1:D1&"♀"&B2:D)), "♀"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

or maybe:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&"♀"&B1:D1&"♀"&B2:D)), "♀"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 
  order by Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) 
  label sum(Col3)''", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, this is what i was looking for. Thank you very much!.