# Column headers to rows

Tags: google-sheets, unpivot

I am trying to convert data in Google Sheets that looks like this:

```
  A.  B.  C
1
2
3
```

to this:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
B 3
C 1
C 2 
C 3
```

And I am trying to make it dynamic such that if you add rows to the first table, the second table gets updated as well. How can i do this? Preferably using a formula instead of Google Apps Script.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a "reverse pivot" in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954722/how-do-you-create-a-reverse-pivot-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or, as an alternative

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Blad2!B1:1, LEN(Blad2!B1:1))&"_"&FILTER(Blad2!A2:A, LEN(Blad2!A2:A))), "_"))
```

[image]

or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(FILTER(Blad2!B1:1, LEN(Blad2!B1:1))&FILTER(Blad2!A2:A, LEN(Blad2!A2:A))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(Flatten(ARRAYFORMULA(concat(CONCAT(INDEX( FILTER( B1:1 , NOT( ISBLANK( B1:1 ) ) ))," "),INDEX( FILTER( A2:A , NOT( ISBLANK( A2:A ) ) )))))," "))
```

[image: sample1]

---

or if your format is: A. B. C. :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(Flatten(ARRAYFORMULA(concat(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX( FILTER( B1:1 , NOT( ISBLANK( B1:1 ) ) )),"."," "),INDEX( FILTER( A2:A , NOT( ISBLANK( A2:A ) ) )))))," "))
```

[image: sample2]

or if you want it in the same column:

---

```
=Flatten(ARRAYFORMULA(concat(INDEX( FILTER( B1:1 , NOT( ISBLANK( B1:1 ) ) )),INDEX( FILTER( A2:A , NOT( ISBLANK( A2:A ) ) )))))
```

[image: sample3]

Comment: **sidenote: this solution has upper limit 50000 characters**

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

1. Use an intermediate sheet for storing the following for each column:

[image]

2. Then split the last column into rows:

[image]

Comment: **sidenote: this solution has upper limit 50000 characters**