# Google Sheets Unpivot/Flatten and Remove Rows with Zeros

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to flatten a table and remove rows with a cell value of zero.

Here is what I've tried so far:

Table 2:

```
={"Customer Name", "Project Name", "Total Hrs", "Workforce","Hrs";ARRAYFORMULA(
     split(
        flatten(
           transpose(query(transpose(B3:D16&"|"),,9^9))&"|"&E2:H2&"|"&E3:H16
        ),"|"
     )
)}
```

My goals is to get to Table 3, but by manipulating the formula I have for Table 2 instead of using the filter formula in a different cell, if possible.
[image: Goal is to move from Table 1 to Table 3]

Comment: Why did you use the `google-apps-script` tag? are you looking for a script solution?

Comment: Yes - if there is a faster way to get from table 1 to table 3 using scripts, then I am open to that. I may have to repost my question to show the script I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

just query it:

```
={"Customer Name", "Project Name", "Total Hrs", "Workforce","Hrs";
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(split(flatten(transpose(
 query(transpose(B3:D16&"|"),,9^9))&"|"&E2:H2&"|"&E3:H16 ),"|" ) , "where Col5 <> 0"))}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually found a solid script to 'unpivot' and then use a query to filter.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954722/how-do-you-create-a-reverse-pivot-in-google-sheets/43681525#43681525