# Google sheets partially unpivot a very long row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, unpivot

Riders sign up for our fundraiser. The form allows from 1-5 riders to register and exports a single row of excel data with 37 columns which I import into Google Sheeets. Each rider has 6 columns of data, the other 7 are info common to all riders.

There will be as many as 200 such rows. Many will contain info for 1 or two riders.

I need a table of riders with all of their info, eliminating the blank riders.

I'm sure this is a query/array problem, but I can't figure it out. I would appreciate any guidance.

Here's a link to test data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/180v1zmRaluh8v9aiqiRcKROUopUQLPWCX09_Dm3ZdgI/edit#gid=0

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: You can try the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098221/google-sheets-unpivot-flatten-and-remove-rows-with-zeros