# Transpose data to database structure in google sheets using google apps script

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GLwRcQ47M-NvIuxZY-VUPyE1qXtprqcmtFaKVXUIzvs/edit?usp=sharing

I have a problem in above google sheets. Basically I want to transpose data horizontal to vertical database. Example like below

Before

```
Name Type 2018 2019 2020 2021
Apple Fix 2000 3000 4000 5000
```

After

```
Name Type Year Value
Apple Fix 2018 2000
Apple Fix 2019 3000
Apple Fix 2020 4000
Apple Fix 2021 5000
```

Right now I do it manually copy and paste. But the data will grow every day. Right now I had almost 1000 rows so doing it manually will not fruitful. I am guessing that I need to make google apps script to solve this problem. May be someone can give suggestion how to solve this problem.

Thanks before

Comment: See tab called Proposal Result with the main formula in B2 `=query(arrayformula(split(flatten(Source!B2:B &"|"& Source!C2:C &"|"& Source!D2:D &"|"& Source!E2:E &"|"& Source!F2:F &"|"& Source!G1:R1 &"|"& Source!G2:R &"|"& Source!S2:S),"|")),"select * where Col2 is not null")`

Comment: Hi @MikeSteelson thanks for the help. I'm sorry if my question is suspected to be duplicate with other similar question. I already give vote up for your answer. The formula Flatten is really new for me. Again many thanks for highlighting it up to me. Now I can work more effective, no need to sit all day long, using your solution. Best regards

Comment: @MikeSteelson Don't see how your solution is different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64389174/ The link provided is exhaustive and perfect.

Comment: About sharing spreadsheets, do note that [it exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). So, use a dummy Google account if you consider your email address to be private.

Comment: @MikeSteelson OP already tagged [google-apps-script]. Almost all answers  there work. It's OP's job to search and research before asking the question. (See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) Even if not, if it's closed as duplicate, op should check all the answers there(barely 10 answers) and use the best thing suited to his needs. If OP can't be bothered to do that, We shouldn't go spoonfeeding OP.

Comment: Alright next time I will use dummy Google account. It's quite new for me. Thanks @TheMaster.