# Multiple columns as a pie chart on Data Studio

Tags: case, dashboard, looker-studio

I'm trying to make a pie chart using three different columns from my [sheets dataset (table 9)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R-AFYUbDz-uVptngJd1P9nKSW9kxvl4zIxemfLpxiqg/edit#gid=2019217740) – *caretaker issues*, *child issues*, and *housing issues*. I'm trying to visualize the percentage/total number for each column in a pie chart, but Data Studio only allows one metric.

Here's how the columns are laid out:
[image]

I've tried grouping them together using these CASE statements, but it only shows numbers as their dimension.

CASE
WHEN Housing_Issues IS NOT NULL THEN Housing_Issues
WHEN Child_Issues IS NOT NULL THEN Child_Issues
WHEN Caretaker_Issues IS NOT NULL THEN Caretaker_Issues
END

Here's the [link](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b3fe40fa-e78e-4f89-85a5-8921c096c9b6) to the dashboard, and the pie chart I'm trying to create is on page 3. Any suggestion? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hybrid approach that first transforms the data in Google Sheets in a process referred to as [unpivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24954722/12892553) and then creates a `Dimension` field in Google Data Studio:

## 1) Google Sheets

Create a new sheet and copy-paste the formula below in cell A1, where `Table 9_AK` represents the sheet name (as shown in the [`DataSet`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DuJflhemWutTgd2hylVqnnF5PO8k6EO__VG14dbOYgE/edit#gid=2058706844) sheet); it also replaces line breaks and `_` with a   (space) in the original headings:

```
=QUERY(
{ArrayFormula(SPLIT(
{FLATTEN('Table 9_AK'!A2:A&"|"&TEXT('Table 9_AK'!B2:B,"DD MMM YYYY")&"|"&TRIM(REGEXREPLACE('Table 9_AK'!C1:AA1,"(_|"&CHAR(10)&")"," "))&"|"&TRIM('Table 9_AK'!C2:AA))},"|",))},"
SELECT *
WHERE Col1 is NOT Null
LABEL Col1 'Agency', Col2 'Date', Col3 'Breakdown Dimension', Col4 'Metric'
",0)
```

<sub>***NOTE***: Data can continue to be added in the original sheet (`Table 9_AK`), and it will automatically be transformed in the [`DataSet`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DuJflhemWutTgd2hylVqnnF5PO8k6EO__VG14dbOYgE/edit#gid=2058706844) sheet</sub>

## 2) Google Data Studio

- Chart: [Pie Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7187587)
- Dimension: `Dimension`

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Breakdown Dimension, ".*(Caretaker).*") THEN "Caretaker Issues"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Breakdown Dimension, ".*(Alleged Neglect|Housing|Abandonment|TPR|Place).*") THEN "Housing Issues"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Breakdown Dimension, ".*(Child|Alleged|Prenatal).*") THEN "Child Issues"
  ELSE "Other"
END
```

- Metric: `Metric`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/46fcbc56-a3ac-4c1c-91f1-86d5e3dc48ea) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DuJflhemWutTgd2hylVqnnF5PO8k6EO__VG14dbOYgE/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 6]