# google spreadsheet how to copy/transform existing row to few rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

google spreadsheet how to copy/transform existing row to few rows copied by count words in colums P by words. Example:

INPUT:

```
date|my name|city|phone|etc data|else data|task1 task2 task3 taskN|data|
date2|my name2|city2|phone2|etc data2|else data2|task1 |data2|
```

OUT:

```
date|my name|city|phone|etc data|else data|task1|data|
date|my name|city|phone|etc data|else data|task2|data|
date|my name|city|phone|etc data|else data|task3|data|
**...**
date|my name|city|phone|etc data|else data|taskN|data|

date2|my name2|city2|phone2|etc data2|else data2|task1|data2|
```

just copy string by count of words in specific column

is it possible to do such an operation with a formula? or only appscript

im trying use appscript, but my realization so bulky and slow (

get words from a cell, possibly by an object or a regular expression, but then it would be possible to duplicate / transpose the content from horizontal to vertical for recording by duplicating data from other cells

Comment: Now, I noticed that you changed your question. I was surprised by it. My answer was for your initial question. In this case, by changing your question, unfortunately, my answer has been not useful. Because my answer is to your initial question. So, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize that I couldn't notice your posted question was not your actual question. I would like to recommend you not to change your question after an answer has been posted.

Comment: Try the [unpivot_()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76843760/13045193) pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a formula option, using REDUCE and SPLIT to stack the values. Please change " " inside SPLIT if your tasks are joined in another way. And G1:G2 to the whole column you need to process:

```
=REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),G1:G2,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="",a,VSTACK(a,
  REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SPLIT(v," "),LAMBDA(b,w,VSTACK(b,HSTACK(INDEX(A:F,ROW(v)),w,INDEX(H:H,ROW(v))))))
))))
```

[image]