How to transpose the data using Appscript
I am new here. I really need your help on my problem here. I have the data which contains name,task,start shift, and end shift for each day. All of them are separated into different columns, and I want to transpose all of them by considering the date in start shift, and end shift using Appscript. The detail can be seen in this sheet textData
Here's the output that I expect
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oAB6PxPHFQHQPFwf-TMgnl0mX4yZT-jLzTpuv7C7_tc/edit?gid=1949317336#gid=1949317336
Ouput

In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/24954722
