# COUNTIFS using REGEX as criteria

Tags: regex, google-sheets, countif

I have this table below:

```
A       B           C
Date .  Place       Person
1/1  .  DOU,DORS    John
1/1  .  DOMG,DOSP   Mark  
2/1  .  DOU,DOSP    Alex
1/1  .  DOU         John
```

I need a formula to `COUNTIF` "Date" is `1/1` and if inside "Place" the string "DOU" is present (I need to do that dynamically with multiple dates and strings, just using this example to simplify).

So basically something like `COUNTIFS(B:B;"DOU";A:A;1/1) = TRUE`

I tried `COUNTIFS(B:B;"DOU";A:A;1/1)` but it didn't work out because it only works with exact matches and not partial strings. If I use `REGEXMATCH(B2;"DOU")` I get `TRUE`, however, I didn't find a way to insert `REGEXMATCH` inside `COUNTIFS` to make it in volume and dynamically. Is there a way to do that? If there is not, is there any way to make this operation?

Also, I tried to use the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515469/google-sheets-pattern-matching-regex-for-countif) however it didn't work out right from the beginning. I'm trying to do `COUNTA(FILTER(B:B;REGEXMATCH(B:B; "DOU")))` but it is always 1 having or not having "DOU" in the column.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73449557/1627401

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I found it out by myself.
Solved my problem using `COUNTIFS(B:B;"*DOU*")`

Answer (score 1):

basically, you need this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B; "*DOU*"; A:A; "1/1")
```